# Flutter showModalBottomSheet resize on drag up

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and just implemented a bottom sheet modal to show some content. However, I would like it to react to drag up  on the `dragHandle` to resize to a larger view (like google maps does it for instance).

I assume I would have to resize my container in the drag event? But is this possible for a sheet that was created with `showModalBottomSheet`?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      showDragHandle: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(28), topRight: Radius.circular(28),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child:
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                            detailWidget(context, content),
                      ]
                      )
              );
      });
```

Comment: I think you should use DraggableScrollableSheet. See the document of [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks. Is this part of the Flutter package or third party?

Comment: Flutter package.